# How to sort all members with a value of false to the end of a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean, stdvector

I want to sort a vector of bools by their value. This is the list:

```
std::vector<bool> bolis {true true false true false false true true};
```

Is there some kind of function that would make this list equal to this:

```
{true,true,true,true,true,false,false,false}
```

I saw the `std::sort` function but it seems the only real use of it is to sort a list of ints or floats and not a list of bools.

Comment: Have a look at [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).

Comment: `std::sort` could certainly be used. However, as there are two values only, simpler solutions certainly exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Method:**

This can be achieved by defining the **custom comparator function** and passing it to the `sort` function.

Have a look at the implementation as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>



//define the function:
bool comparator(bool lhs, bool rhs) { return rhs < lhs; }

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> bolis {true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true};
    
    // pass it to sort:
    sort(bolis.begin(), bolis.end(), &comparator);
    
    for(int i=0;i<bolis.size();i++){
        std::cout<<(bolis[i] ? "true " : "false ");
    }
    std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

**Output:**

```
true true true true true false false false
```

**Second method in O(N) time complexity:**

Count the number of true and false values in the vector and print them accordingly.

For example, if there are 5 true values and 2 false values, then print true for 5 number of number of times and false for 2 number of times.

Or you can push the values in another vector as well **or edit the original vector.**

**Thanks to @john for all the suggestions to improve the answer!**

Comment: Thanks @John. Changed it.

Comment: No problem. I like the mention of O(N) in your answer. A vector of bools can obviously be sorted in O(N) just by counting and then assigning false or true in the appropriate places.

Comment: Thanks @John! Also added your suggestion about editing the original vector.

Comment: `comparator` is not needed (default one is correct).

Answer (score 1):

To sort a `std::vector<bool>` is a very specific case, and can be done by a very specific solution:

counting the number of `true` elements and then rewrite the vector based on this count.

Sample code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::vector<bool> bolis {true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true};
  // count number of true
  size_t nT = 0;
  for (bool value : bolis) nT += value == true;
  // write sorted vector
  for (size_t i = 0, n = bolis.size(); i < n; ++i) bolis[i] = i < nT;
  // show result
  const char *sep = "";
  for (bool value : bolis) {
    std::cout << sep << std::boolalpha << value;
    sep = ", ";
  }
}
```

Output:

```
true, true, true, true, true, false, false, false
```

[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ebe105668e85108e)

Answer (score 0):

The [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) function from the standard library is designed for doing exactly what you want to do. It accepts a range and a predicate, and reorders the elements of the range so that they are partitioned according to this predicate:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> bolis {true, true, false, true, false, false, true, true};

    //reorder so that true comes first    
    std::partition(bolis.begin(), bolis.end(), [](bool b){return b;});

    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::copy(bolis.begin(), bolis.end(), std::ostream_iterator<bool>(std::cout, " " ));
    
    return 0;    
}
```

Output:

```
true true true true true false false false
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f68Mn5).